# Passing data between two applications via third application

Tags: asp.net, session, iframe, cookies, web-farm

I have an asp.net application containing two pages Add/Edit Customer and Customer List(View).
There is one more host ASP.NET application that uses ajax tab container/accordian to host above two pages in iframes. So as shown below TAB1 contains Edit Customer Page in iframe 1 and TAB2 contains View Customers Page(only one can be active at a time). If I have to move from TAB2 to TAB1 (e.g. user clicks on edit link in customer list), then I have to refresh host application by passing name of tab in querystring(This part is handled by the Host App and is the only available way to switch TAB).

What is the best way to pass data from TAB2 to TAB1 other than query string? I don't want to change host app url by appending querystring as it will be hard to reset the querystring without reloading. My application is in webfarm and has IP session affinity based load balancer. We use in proc session currently but it fails occasionally which is obvious. Are there any proven ways to handle this scenario in webfarm if I remove out-proc sessions out of the question?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------

ASP.NET MAIN APP CONTENT

   VirDir-B

[parent]
**________________________________________________________________**

TAB1                         | TAB2

[iframe1]                    | [iframe2]    

{  Edit Cust                 | {  View Cust 
       VirDir-A }            |          VirDir A  }
                             |
```

**UPDATE** :

Well, I solved this problem using javascript by directly setting source of iframe1 with querystring parameter as all my VDs are in same domain.

**PSEUDO CODE:**

On View Page:

```
var tabContainer=$(parent.document).find('#TABCONTAINERID').control;
var iframe=$(parent.document).find('#TABCONTAINERID').children('#iframe1');
iframe.src="editCust.aspx?id=123"
tabContainer.set_activeTabIndex(0);
```

But I'm curious to know how this could have been handled if I had no control over parent application(may be in different domain).

Answer (score -1):

At least two methods I can think of could be used:

- Passing the data to a cookie, then reading it on the other tab
- Sending the data to the ASP.NET host app using ajax and downloading it on the other tab